# Issue with adjusting position for grouped buttons in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have added the data-type="horizontal" attribute to the controlgroup container. Where I have added one select menu and one plus icon. so that the user select existing category or add new category. Now I want that "+" icon should always fix at right corner to margin remaining space should occupy the select box. My code is as follows,

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
                     <option value="Select Category">Select Category</select>
                    </select>
                     <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
                  </div>
```

And my screen shot is as follows for above code. I want that "+" symbol should fix at right margin with only icon size. Is it possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning CSS to accomplish this:

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 42px;
}
.ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-select{
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    right: 73px;
}
.ui-controlgroup-controls a.ui-btn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px; left: auto;   
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5haP6/)**

[image]

Comment: I need the same. But the bottom corners for select menu and icon does not matching

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the 2 buttons joined, but rather separate with all 4 corners of each rounded? The demo fiddle I created has the same corners as your original screenshot (see screenshot I added to the answer).

Comment: My screen shot as I shared is second page which is fired by on click event of button in first page. So this is in second page. Where should  I need to write the above css code. I tried in written in script tag it does not work. Where exactly I need to write the css code

Comment: Don't you have a site wide CSS file?  You can load it at the top of your main page and it should apply accross all pages if you are using AJAX navigation.  If you are not using AJAX navigation, you would need to include this along with all other css and js in each separate file.